# Using Angular Material Paginator with Observable and without tables

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable, paginator

(Please help, still not resolved)So I am following this [stackoverflow(with mat-card)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54369230/14985824) and [this(with observable)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58843398/14985824) in combination to try to solve my problem.

I have an observable of an array of objects, and I want to use `*ngFor` along with `mat-card` to display them, and then there's a paginator at the very bottom of the page.

Right now, The observables are linked up properly(because it's displaying), but the paginator doesn't seem to show anything([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mPde.png)), wondering if anyone could help, thank you so much!

(There's a lot of code for other functionalities, so I will try my best to only list out the ones we need, if you feel like there's anything missing please let me know)

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="obs| async as objects>
 <div>
  <div>
   <mat-card *ngFor="let ob of objects"> ... </mat-card>
  </div>
  <mat-paginator
  [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
  [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]"> 
  </mat-paginator>
 </div>
```

TS:
Side note: `filtered$` is the original observable of array I used for the `mat-card`, now I'm adding paginator, so in HTML you can see I changed to `obs`

```
public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
obs: Observable<any>;
public filtered$: Observable<Array<An Object>>;

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef){};

ngOnInit(){
...;
  this.filtered$
  .pipe(takeUntil(...))
  .subscribe((arr) => (this.dataSource.data = arr));
 this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
 this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
 this.obs = this.dataSource.connect();
}
```

Comment: Even if I added `[length]="objects.length"`, it is displaying the numbers on the paginator, but the functionalities are not working

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the dataSource on table

or if you want to use without table and dataSource you need to menage the total data on paginator

```
             <mat-paginator 
                (page)="onPageChange($event)"
                [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
                [length]="total"
                [pageSize]="limit"
                [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
            </mat-paginator>
```

where total is total items and limitSize is the number of product for page

Comment: Thank you. I don't think you will "need" to use dataSource on table? From one of the links I attached above, one did not use table. And I'm wondering if you could tell me what you did with the `onPageChange($event)` function? And doesn't the "`pageSizeOptions`" determine the "`pageSize`"?

Comment: @WendyZhang, `pageSizeOptions` does not determine the `pageSize`. Because `pageSize` is the default number of elements you want on a single page. And `pageSizeOptions` are the options to choose from.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like the `pageSize` is not the problem here

Comment: Check out my answer.

Comment: @ZunayedShahriar Yeah thanks I did. There are some comments underneath. I'm assuming you are using`*ngFor = pagedDataArray`? But I thought that's not how paginator should work. `*ngFor` should include all elements inside the array. If it doesn't, then my other functionalities won't work... And there are some errors with `Cannot read property 'slice' of null`

Comment: @WendyZhang, I've said earlier. You need to load all the data first. Then you should filter.

Comment: @ZunayedShahriar If I need **all** the data in my html for other purposes what should I do? And could you give me a quick code example to conclude your response? Thank you

Comment: @WendyZhang
You can change the default page size to a large number like 1M.
That should do the work and if the users want to see fewer items then they can change the page size from options.

Note: Loading too much data in HTML may slow your particular component's performance.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:** You have to keep separate arrays or observables. One for showing paged data and another to store all the data.

**HTML:**

```
<mat-paginator *ngIf="total > 0"
    [length]="total"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [pageIndex]="pageIndex"
    (page)="pageChanged($event)"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

**Note:** I think you should not show paginator when you do not have any data.

**Typescript:**

```
pageChanged(event: any) {
    this.pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
    this.setFilteredData();
}

setFilteredData() {
    this.yourPagedDataArray = this.yourAllDataArray.slice(this.pageSize * this.pageIndex, this.pageSize * this.pageIndex + this.pageSize);
}
```

**Note:** You need to call the `setFilteredData()` method after your data fetching is completing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm just wondering about what is the difference between "pagedDataArray" and "allDataArray"? 
Since now I only have observables, but no raw arrays, how could I use `slice` without using subscribe?

Comment: And now my understanding is that if `pagedDataArray` is for this current page/s info, while `allDataArray` is for all. But when do I use the `pagedDataArray`? In my HTML, I'm always using the `allDataArray` **observable**